# No call audio when using lightning to 3.5mm adapter

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I'm trying to use 3.5mm headphones with my iPhone 11 running iOS 15.3. I've tried a few different lightning to 3.5mm adapters and they have the same issue: music, games, videos work great; phone or Zoom calls always play from the phone's built-in speakers rather than the headphones. Even voicemail playback goes to the phone speakers rather than headphones.

When I bring up the audio devices in Control Center, the adapter + headphones show as "Dock speaker". I tried setting Accessibility > Call Audio Routing to "Speaker", but otherwise I'm not seeing any switches to flip. And searches on these keywords are flooded with results for broken connectors and the like so I'm having trouble finding anyone having this same issue.

Using the Apple wired lighting connector earbuds from a previous works fine, so phone-over-lightning *can* work, just not with any of the 3.5mm adapters I've tried? Any help or 3.5mm adapter recommendations appreciated.